# Is there a way to rename the username on the Zoom Linux client from the terminal?

Tags: zoom-meeting

I tried changing stuff on `~/.config/zoomus.config` but, in that file is not the display username shown.

I'm on a remote server, so it'd be nice to know.

Comment: I never knew that file existed, good to know. Actually I just had an unusual experience where the zoom linux client after a fresh install seemed to know a display username. Probably it read it from there or another config file (in `~/.zoom/` ) but maybe it lifts the account name of the logged in linux user out of the system at times. Just a guess, but it may be a reason to rename the user.